# Streaming with OBS to Twitch results in a small (5 - 20) ping increase

Tags: streaming, upload, lag

First time posting here, but I couldn't find a question that was similar to this.

Previously when I tried streaming, my ping for League of Legends would go from 34 to 60 - 180. However, after I upgraded everything, I receive anywhere from 39 to 60~ ping. This is playable but still not optimal.

I recently upgraded both my service, router, and modem to newest models and constructed a new computer, so hardware issues are not the problem.

speedtest.net puts my download speed at 33.48 mbps and upload at 4.15 mbps.

I have gone into my internet settings, and made sure that my Quality of Service both had no restriction and gave gaming data priority over all other data sent.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I am experiencing these small ping spikes and how I might fix them?

Thanks for any and all help :)

(also, if I should post this in a different stackexchange area, just let me know)

Comment: You posted it already here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253837/how-can-i-minimise-ping-time-when-streaming-to-twitch-via-obs and the presumable answer has been given in the comments

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's been [crossposted](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/253837/how-can-i-minimise-ping-time-when-streaming-to-twitch-via-obs). Please don't cross post.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds fairly normal really. Your upload speed is likely a limiting factor of this.

Twitch (as an example) guidelines specify a [maximum bit rate of 3500kbps](http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1253460-broadcast-requirements), which isn't too far off your maximum upload speed. Perhaps consider trying different streaming software which may be more efficient, or lowering the quality slightly, although a 5-20ms ping increase when your ping is already very low seems quite reasonable.

Alternatively, if you're taking this particularly seriously, it may be worth looking to see if your ISP, or another, can provide you a higher upload speed. You could at least, as a test, drop the quality very low (far lower than you'd consider actually streaming at) and see how much of an impact it has, slowly bringing the quality up and seeing if you can observe these spikes start to happen.